# Dictionary lookup fails

Tags: excel, dictionary

I am writing an Excel VBA program that validates a school course schedule.  A key component is a global dictionary object that keeps track of the course number (the key) and the number of times that course is scheduled (the item).  I have successfully created and loaded the dictionary.  I'm trying to lookup the value associated with the course key, but have been unable to do so using the one-line examples I've found at this site.  I'd like to use this line of code:

intCourseCnt = gdicCourses("BAAC 100")

or

intCourseCnt = gdicCourses.Item("BAAC 100")

but neither work (actually, the "BAAC 100" part is a string variable, but it won't even work if I hardcode a course in.)  Instead, I have to use the kludgy loop code below to lookup the course count:

```
Private Function Check_Course_Dup_Helper(strCourse As String) As Boolean
    Dim k As Variant
    Check_Course_Dup_Helper = False
    ' Read thru dictionary. Look to see if only 1 occurrence then jump out.
    For Each k In gdicCourses.Keys
        If k = strCourse Then
            If gdicCourses.Item(k) = 1 Then
                Check_Course_Dup_Helper = True
                Exit Function
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
     Next
End Function
```

Is there a way to rewrite this so that I can lookup of the item value without the loop?

Thank you.

Comment: You say "but neither work" -- what does this mean? What happens if you do `gdicCourses(strCourse)`?

Comment: You might also consider showing the code you use to populate this dictionary. It seems likely that you're populating with data that is not *quite* what you think it is (perhaps leading/trailing spaces or non-printing characters, etc.)

Comment: Check that (1) The dictionary does exist and does contain that exact key - and double check what exactly your key is - whitespace included  (2) Try populating the dictionary in alphabetical order and then searching for it

Comment: If, in fact, your dictionary is set up as you write, then your test lines should work.  I agree with @DavidZemens that there may be a problem in how you have set up your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the prompt replies.  Answers below:

David, the **gdicCourses("BAAC 100")** code value while the program is running is "empty" which makes the receiving variable equal to 0.  The result is the same if I use strCourse variable.  Also, the dictionary populating code is shown below.  I do not believe it is a problem because I can correctly access the values elsewhere in the program where For-Each-Next loops that use a range variable are employed.  Whitespace and non-printable characters are not present. 
 My guess is that I need to use a range to reference the position in the dictionary rather than a string.  I've tried pretty much every combination of this that I can think of, but the value is still "empty".

```
Set gdicCourses = New Scripting.Dictionary
For Each c In Worksheets("Tables").Range("combined_courses").Cells
    If Not (gdicCourses.Exists(c)) Then
        gdicCourses.Add c, (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIF(Range("MWF_Table_Full"), c
                           (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("TTh_Table_Full"), c)))
    End If
Next
```